# VBScript to delete the row if particular column cell value is empty (based on Column name)

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am new to VBScript. I need little help on deleting the entire row in excel based on particular column value (trying to pass the column name as argument, Column name will be vary everytime). Based on the column name, script should check the cells and if any cell contains empty value then delete the entire row.

Any help would be appreciate.

```
Dim objExcel, objWorkbook, objSheet, objWorksheet

Const xlCellTypeBlanks = 4

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\test.xlsx")
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Sheets(1)
a = "LastName"
With Columns(a)
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End With
```

This is my code but it is not working as expected

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the worksheet's MATCH function through Excel.Application to get the ordinal position of the column by matching the column header label in row 1.

```
Dim objExcel, objWorkbook, objSheet, objWorksheet

Const xlCellTypeBlanks = 4

'Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\test.xlsx")
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Sheets(1)
a = "LastName"
With objWorksheet.Columns(objExcel.match(a, objWorksheet.rows(1), 0))
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End With
```